# IE not showing image that is positioned absolute

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple image tag that is not showing up in IE, I have messed around with the firebug and when I set the position to something else than absolute it does show, why does absolute not work? Is there anyway to fix my problem?

My image tag:

```
<div class="container-fluid header">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
               <a href="/" id="logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">

           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4" >

           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

I also do this in a media query maybe it's relevant because when the screen is smaller then 992px the image is shown:

```
@media (max-width: 992px){
    #logo img {
        position: relative !important;
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Css:

```
#logo img{
    margin-top: 50px !important; 
    position: absolute !important;
    max-width: 438px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: and it is ok in chrome or firefox??

Comment: @DanyCode Yeah works fine everywhere else :)

Comment: We will need a minimal, verifiable example. Just having a piece of CSS won't help, especially without actual positioning information. There is no general problem with absolute positioning in IE.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'll edit OP with more HTML and CSS

Comment: can you provide more code along with your example? how are the parent elements set up?

Comment: I don't think it is that but did you put something like this in the head of your HTML?                              <!--[if lt IE9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: @DanyCode No I did not

Comment: this is a comment who can help with IE

Comment: is this all relevant styling? including for the `#logo` element as well? If you positioning this element with `absolute` that means it will be absolutely positioned to the nearest positioned parent. So if it's parent container is not positioned, it will be absolutely positioned to the document `body` if no parents is positioned. More styling code will help debug this, **as well as an example of this issue (on jsfiddle or in question)**.

Comment: Yeah it's relevant because the `.header` has a background color and I want the logo to stick out of the header notice the `margin-top: 50px`

Comment: http://www.geekmaispasque.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Test_html5shiv_geekmaispasque.jpg on the left you chave the page without the comment and on the right with the script

Comment: @DanyCode what is the full comment exactly because the link is broken that you posted

Comment: <!--[if lt IE9]> <script src="html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></…; <![endif]-->

Comment: @FrankLucas I am not sure you understood my comment about relevancy. I was asking you if you included all styling code that is related to this issue. I already know the answer is *no* because it is damn near impossible to recreate this issue with the code you've given us. At this point you'll likely be receiving guesses as to how to solve your issue (and sometimes that works).

Comment: @Quoid I've been messing around a bit and I think the issue is the `max-width` when I switch `max-width` with `width` it seems to work okay